# Tricks between plain python script and functions?

Tags: python

As a very newbie to programming, I tried to test every function individually, make sure it works right.
Here is my problem: for single plainly test, it works; turn it to functions and combine them into a script, them don't work.
**For example:**

```
def getRigs (fileObj):
    fileObj.seek(0)
    rigList = []
    Tag = False
    for line in fileObj:
        if line.find("[BeginRigs]") != -1:
            Tag = True
        elif line.find("[EndRigs]") != -1:
            Tag = False
        elif Tag:
            rigList.append(line.strip())
    return (rigList)

def getObjects (fileObj):
    fileObj.seek(0)
    objList = []
    Tag = False
    for line in fileObj:
        if line.find("[BeginObjects]") != -1:
            Tag = True
        elif line.find("[EndObjects]") != -1:
            Tag = False
        elif Tag:
            objList.append(line.strip())
    return (objList)

def dummyRig (rigObj, objName):
    dummy = ""
    for rig in rigObj:
        with open(rig, "r") as infile:
            #rigObj.seek(0)
            Tag = None
            for line in infile:
                for obj in objName:
                    if line.find("ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n") !=-1:
                        Tag = "Mark"
                        dummy += line
                        break
                    elif line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                        if Tag == "Mark":
                            Tag = "Copy"
                        break
                    elif line.find("EndKeyframe") != -1:
                        if Tag == "Copy":
                            Tag = None
                            dummy += line
                        break
                if Tag == "Copy":
                    dummy += line
    return (dummy)

def getBlock (rigObj, objName):
    Tag = False
    block = ""
    for line in rigObj:
        if line.find("ObjectAlias " + str(objName) + "\n") != -1:
            for line in rigObj:
                if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                    Tag = True
                elif line.lstrip().startswith("0.000 ") and line.rstrip().endswith("default"):
                    Tag = False
                    break
                elif Tag:
                    block += line
    return (block)

inputconfig = open("config.cfg", "r")
infile = sys.argv[1]
inputscene = open(infile, "r")
outfile = infile.split(".")[0] + "_updated.fxs"
outputscene = open(outfile, "w")

a_rigList = getRigs (inputconfig)
a_objList = getObjects (inputconfig)

a_dummyRig = dummyRig (a_rigList, a_objList)
#print a_dummyRig    #----> Output as expected
tmp = getBlock (a_dummyRig, a_objList)
outputscene.write(tmp)    #----> Gvie me empty output!
```

If I test "getBlock" function individually, it works fine:

```
with open("result_from_a_dummyRig", "r") as rigObj, open("result", "w") as output:
    Tag = False
    for line in rigObj:
        if line.find("ObjectAlias " + "rooster_bn_featherLa_rt_08" + "\n") != -1:
            for line in rigObj:
                if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                    Tag = True
                elif line.lstrip().startswith("0.000 ") and line.rstrip().endswith("default"):
                    Tag = False
                    break
                elif Tag:
                    output.write(line)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Add more of my code, hope it helps for the question. The code is design for copy some external data from other files to update my current files.
Thanks ***bruno***, I got your point. The dummyRig function give me a string but not a "real" file. And getBlock function needs a "real" file input. Right?
Still hope someone give me more useful helps, I am not a programmer, I don't know much about python.

Comment: can you please provide sample inputs and expected outputs as well as the stack trace?

Comment: File object is an iterator, after the first for-loop is it going to be empty. Use its [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method to move the file pointer back to the start.

Comment: where did you define `a_objList`? and why do you call `get_block()` with a string (the return of `dummyRig()`) when it seems to expect an object?

Comment: The bulk of your question is explicitly given as an *example* of a question which is too broad for Stack Overflow since you are essentially asking "how does modular programming work?"

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I was suspecting something like that, but the code is too thick.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Python don't allow me use seek(0) if rigObj is a list of file, look at dummyRig function where I uncommented. I don't know why

Comment: @Aemyl: It just a part of my script. I think getBlock will give me a block of data like a normal input file. Look at my comment (#print a_dummyRig    #----> Output as expected)

Comment: @Tian It would be nice to see a bit more of your code, just to understand what it does

Answer (score 0):

In your "test", you are iterating over an opened file. The file iterator iterate over the file's lines.

In your script, what you're passing to `getBlock` is a string, so you're iterating over the string's individual characters. No surprise you don't get the same results.

If you want `getBlock` to be able to work on both an opened file OR some arbitray string, you have to wrap the string in some file-like object that will iterate over line, not chars. The stdlib's [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module comes to mind...

Also if you really want to be serious about tests, use some automated unittest framework (unittest might not be the most sexy but it's in the stdlib) and make sure you really test the same thing that you will pass to your function ;)